# How I can select all categories of Joomla! in another PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have another script that I'm trying to read all categories of my Joomla! in my script.

There's my PHP code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("kkj");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jo_categories");
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

I have 4 rows in this table.

But `$array` is only first rows of that.

Why can not select all rows?
What is the problem?

Comment: You will need a `while` loop over `mysql_fetch_assoc` to fetch all results.

Comment: Why don't you start to learn PDO, these `mysql_*` functions are anyway deprecated and it will be good for you ... [HERE](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a nice tutorial ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just starting to learn this you should start with PDO, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

[HERE](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) you have a nice tutorial.

To answer you question, you need to loop results like

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

}
```

Much elegant in PDO:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kkj;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM jo_categories");
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

connection with `UTF8` and full array without looping.